# How can I combine two arrays with special parameters using Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['1', '2', '3']
```

how can I combine them in one array called let's say "c" and which have the following view:

```
c = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the the built-in functions `map` and `zip` with `str.join`:

```
list(map(''.join, zip(a, b)))
```

output:

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip` will allow you to match the corresponding indexes:

```
result = [''.join(x) for x in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this (**Other than using zip function**)

```
>>>[j + b[i] for i, j in enumerate(a)]
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```